# how to open an apk file from a webpage in php

Tags: javascript, java, php

I created an android application that reads the qr code, collects data and opens a web page in php where the data is collected through the $ _GET function, once the script is finished I would like the application to reopen in automatic.
is there any function or method in php that makes me automatically open an apk app installed in the device?
if it can't be done in php, how could i do?

Comment: That is obviously not possible as its a big security risk. I think what you want could be achieved with deep links https://medium.com/@ageitgey/everything-you-need-to-know-about-implementing-ios-and-android-mobile-deep-linking-f4348b265b49

Comment: Sounds like you should just be making an API request instead of opening a web page

Comment: @Chris Haas I don't know, it's the first time I've approached these things.
basically I want the same effect that comes when you open facebook from the browser and you are asked to want to open the app already installed, I don't know if I have explained myself

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to "open a web page" beyond just sending data to a server? Is the user supposed to do something or see something?

Comment: no, actually no, I simply send the data via the url and retrieve it with a GET, and I wouldn't know how to do it differently without opening the browser to run the php script, but the user doesn't have to do anything. is there any way not to open the browser?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything too specific about Android programming, but if you do a search for Android REST API request, or Java REST API request you should find many, many answers. Don't spend too much time (yet) worrying about API redesign, for now just learn about how you can use it to send HTTP GET/POST requests to a server without a "visual" browser/client